# React Native Testing - How to TDD and test components beyond snapshots?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tdd, jestjs

I'm really struggling with how to test React Native components beyond using snapshots from jest. Those are great for testing the look of something based on some data passed into a component, but it doesn't seem like there is a way to test events or event handlers, checking if event listeners were setup or disconnected correctly in lifecycle methods, etc...like it feels like I'm either missing something or the tooling is not complete.

Also on a side note snapshot testing feels backwards in terms of TDD since you can only write your tests once you have your application code...any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

With snapshot test you can only check the values in props and styles etc. To check some logic in container i used 'shallow' from enzyme ;)

Comment: Right but that still only applies to testing the rendered output. How would you go about testing an event handler? For example that when you press a TouchableHighlight Component, that it navigates to a new component and make sure its the right one? Or simulate and press and check that it makes an ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use snapshots with events for things like: click a button and verify the rendered output after the click:

```js
it('should render Markdown in preview mode', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MarkdownEditor value="*Hello* Jest!" />
  );

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

  wrapper.find('[name="toggle-preview"]').simulate('click');

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

To test that event handler was called property you can do something like that:

```js
it('should pass a selected value to the onChange handler', () => {
  const value = '2';
  const onChange = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Select items={ITEMS} onChange={onChange} />
  );

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

  wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', {
    target: { value },
  });

  expect(onChange).toBeCalledWith(value);
});
```

(Both examples are from my article on [testing React components with Jest](http://blog.sapegin.me/all/react-jest).)